# ssh, nohup, then copy results back

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, nohup

I want a script which automates the running of big mathematical computing jobs on a remote machine. Currently I do this:

- `ssh` into remote machine; run matlab script
- periodically check in to see if job is done yet
- when job is done, I manually `scp` the files containing the results back to my home machine.

I tried to use these kind of lines in my script to do this job (note the script runs on my machine):

```
ssh nohup matlab -r theScript; exit;
scp remote@~/files ~/files
```

This doesn't work. After a while the ssh session ends and the script just proceeds to do the scp, even though the job is not finished yet and the files don't exist yet.

I think what I need to do is check periodically whether the job is done, perhaps by ssh'ing in periodically and reading the `nohup.out` file looking for a `DONE!` signal using grep. Then when I see that, copy the files back. But this seems complicated and I don't know how to get the `DONE!` message back to my computer to run a conditional on (if you see the `DONE` signal, do this stuff...) any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, the ssh could time out or something. So yeah, you best option is to poll. e.g.

```
RUN="$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)"
ssh remote " nohup bash -c \"( matlab -r theScript; echo \$? > $RUN.done ) >$RUN.log 2>&1 </dev/null &\" "
DONE=""
while [ -z "$DONE" ]
do
    sleep 60
    DONE="$(ssh cat $RUN.done 2>/dev/null)"
done
if [ $DONE -eq 0 ]
then
    scp ...
else
    # Optionally fetch logfile
    # scp $RUN.log@remote ...
    echo "ERROR in remote matlab...."
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a way to configure this in your `ssh_config`.

This page explain how: http://nileshbansal.blogspot.com/2007/02/prevent-timeouts-in-ssh.html

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `ServerAliveInterval` in you `ssh_config` file. That way, your SSH session will not close until the remote command finishes.

See [here](http://www.openssh.org/faq.html#2.12).